# UICollectionView-refreshing: getting each cell more than one time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, swift5

Hi I'm having the issue that after refreshing my collectionView I am getting each cell twice on 
my view. And after refreshing a second time I am getting each cell 3 times. I am also getting this issue when presenting the view with a segue a second time.

How can I fix that?

Can someone help me?

### Thank you in advance!!!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
@IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

    var posts = [Post]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionview.refreshControl = refreshControl
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWeatherData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor(hex: "#F17D32")


    }


 @objc private func refreshData(_ sender: Any) {

        fetchData()
        posts.removeAll()
        collectionview.reloadData()

    }

    private func fetchData() {

       getPost()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()


    }


func getPosts(){

            let ref = Database.database().reference()

                            ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in


                                let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

                                for (_,post) in postsSnap {


                                                let posst = Post()
                                                if let author = post["author"] as? String, late date = post["date"], let postID = post["postID"] as? String, let userID = post["userID"] as? String  {
                                                    posst.date = date
                                                    posst.author = author
                                                    posst.postID = postID
                                                    posst.userID = userID

                                                     self.posts.sort(by: {$0.postdateprog > $1.postdateprog})
                                                    self.posts.append(posst)
                                                }



                                        self.collectionview.reloadData()
                                    }

                            })



        }

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print(posts.count)
        return self.posts.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        cell.authorlabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].author
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: self.collectionview.frame.width / 2 - 20, height: self.collectionview.frame.width * 0.7)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase functions are asynchronous and the code in the closure will be called after the synchronous code runs. In other words, you have this

```
   fetchData()
   posts.removeAll()
   collectionview.reloadData()
```

but `posts.removeAll()` and `collectionview.reloadData()` will be called *before* the array is populated.

So here's a truncated overview of the order in which things should be called.

```
@objc private func refreshData(_ sender: Any) {
   self.loadFirebaseData()
}

func loadFirebaseData() {
   ...
   self.posts = []
   for (_,post) in postsSnap {
      self.posts.append(posst)
   }
   self.posts.sort(by: {$0.postdateprog > $1.postdateprog}
   self.collectionview.reloadData()
}
```

Notice that I moved the sort and the reloadData outside of the for loop. There's no reason to call those functions over and over as the datasource is being populated. Do it after that task is complete.